# Can I specify the width and height of each elements in a collectionView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know I can specify the ItemsSpacing to set the space of each elements

but I can not find a property to specify the element's height and width

I have to set the width value to each element?

I want to each element has a same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the **DataTemplate** with the same size . You don't need to set the value of each elements . You can use data binding and set the height and width in code behind or ViewModel .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="contentPage"   // set the name of the contentpage
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
```

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Frame WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.FrameWidth}" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.FrameHeight}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                   
   </Frame>
</DataTemplate>
```

#### in Code Behind

```
public double FrameHeight { get; private set; }
public double FrameWidth { get; private set; }

//...

FrameHeight = xxx;
FrameWidth = xxx;
```

If you just want to set the size of control(like button or label),here is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013166/how-to-make-square-buttons-grid-in-xamarin-forms/56014484#56014484) maybe can help you .

Comment: I mean even I set a value such as 60,HeightRequest=60,there is no effects

Comment: I asked a new question please see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727813/i-can-not-specify-a-height-of-a-customview

Comment: They are different issues ,if my answer helps you ,you an firstly accept it , and I will check another question .